# Error: read ECONNRESET when using PayPal-node-SDK

Tags: node.js, paypal

I am using PayPal-node-SDK module in my Node JS application to create a payout.
My code is

```
   var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
   paypalRequest = { sender_batch_id: 'h4mq5b3xr',
                    email_subject: 'You have a payment' },
                    items: 
                          [ { recipient_type: 'EMAIL',
                            amount: { value: 100, currency: 'USD' },
                            receiver: //sandbox text account,
                           note: 'Thank you.' } ] 
                  }
                  return paypal.payout.create(paypalRequest, true, function (paypalErr, paypalResponse) {
                      console.log('paypalErr',paypalErr);
                      console.log('paypalResponse',paypalResponse);
                  }
```

But when i call the function i am getting the error

```
paypalErr { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
paypalResponse undefined
```

can anyone suggest what is the error and how can i rectify it? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When run the corresponding function , i was using the local url (eg: 192.122.2.2) . That why it was showing the error. But when i tried to run the same on live (eg www.example.net) the function is working properly.

It worked for me. I am not sure it is the correct answer. But it solved my problem.